# Android checkbox list - check uncheck not working propery

Tags: android, listview, checkboxlist

I have checkbox list with adapter. When user click all checkbox on list gets alert "all cheked". Everything work fine when user click on rows but if he click on checkbox he change status (check mark) but doesn't execute method - onItemClick. Some times some items fires method but I can't find relation.
When i click on checkbox chekedValue dosn't change. In this situation user can cheat application :-).
My code:

```
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    cb.performClick();
    if (cb.isChecked()) {
        Log.v("Cheked clik OK ","");
        checkedValue.add(tv.getText().toString());
       // tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.linia_przekreslenie);
        checkAllMarks();
    } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
        Log.v("Cheked clik uncheck ","");
        checkedValue.remove(tv.getText().toString());
       // tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));

    }


}

private void checkAllMarks() {

    int sizeCheckedValue = checkedValue.size();
    int sizePackageList1 = packageList1.size();
     Log.v("chekedvalue " + Integer.toString(sizeCheckedValue), "Package " + sizePackageList1);
     Log.v("chekedValue1 " +checkedValue, " ");

    if (sizeCheckedValue == sizePackageList1) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle(R.string.ready_to_go);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            }
        });


        alert.show();
    }
}

.....My list_item.xml
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well The Problem is that when you click on the row of ListView then onItemClick event is called but when you click on the checkbox only the checkbox event is called not the onItemclik that's why your desired operation in not executing.

what you can do is to have a **CheckedChangeListener** in your adapter class and there you write your logic.

For Reference check below link it contain code that changes the state of checkbox when you click on it.

http://www.androprogrammer.com/2013/10/list-view-with-check-box-using-custom.html